# how to compare value of one key to another in same array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [total_count] => 1
        [view_date] => 2017-03-08
        [rect_title] => demo Company
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [total_count] => 2
        [view_date] => 2017-03-09
        [rect_title] => demo Company
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [search_count] => 1
        [search_date] => 2017-03-09
        [rect_title] => demo Company
    )

)
```

And  I want to compare if `view_date == search_date` then it show in a table like

[image]

Comment: Why do the elements have different keys? How did you end up with these mixed into the same array?

Answer (score 1):

Use the loop on array like if your array name is say **companydetails** then you can loop the array like below.

```
<?php 
    $size = sizeof(companydetails);
    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
      //You can access every single array element here 
      //if you have the value for search_date the use if condition
      if(search_date == companydetails[$i]['view_date']){
        echo "<tr><td>companydetails[$i]['rect_title']</td><td>companydetails[$i]['total_count']</td><td>companydetails[$i]['view_date']</td><td>any other u have in array</td></tr>"
      }
    }
?>
```

The above code will check the view_date from array and compare it with search_date if the condition satisfies then the **tr** will print other it will skip and check for another array value

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new array with the date as key.

```
foreach($array as $v)
{
  $k = isset($v['search_date']) ? $v['search_date'] : $v['view_date'];
  $date[$k][] = $v;
}
```

then the $date save the elements with same search_date or view_date in a subarray.